# Can anybody help me? my app won't run even though it have no error. every time I run my app it crashes

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is a Custom listview on the android studio. here's the code.

here's the XML
activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView">

    </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

here's the XML
row.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="16dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/full_name"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:id="@+id/Full_NameTV"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/section"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#a9a9a9a9"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:id="@+id/SectionTV"
                tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here's the java code
MainActivity.java

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    String[] mFull_Name = {"User 1", "User 2", "User 3", "User 4"};
    String[] mSection = {"User 1 Section", "User 2 Section", "User 3 Section", "User 4 Section"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         listView = findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, mFull_Name, mSection);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

      listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                if (position == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User 1 Section", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                 if (position == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User 2 Section", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (position == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User 3 Section", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (position == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User 4 Section", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        });
    }

        class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {


            String[] rFull_Name;
            String[] rSection;

            MyAdapter(Context c, String[] Full_Name, String[] Section) {
                super(c, R.layout.row, R.id.listView, Full_Name);

                this.rFull_Name = Full_Name;
                this.rSection = Section;

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
                TextView myFull_Name = row.findViewById(R.id.Full_NameTV);
                TextView mySection = row.findViewById(R.id.SectionTV);


                return row;
            }
        }
    }
```

every time I run it crashes but whenever I try to delete the java codes it runs. I don't know what's the problem or what is the error. I've been debugging it for almost 1 day now.

Comment: Please, post the crash log.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)